# Trouble running a C code with arguments from python's subprocess.call

Tags: python, c, subprocess

I'm kind of new to Python and trying to figure something out. I am trying to write a quick script to do parameter testing for a C code that I've written.

The part that is getting to me is when I try to use subprocess.call in order to run my C code. The C code has one argument that is the name of a file that is opened within the code itself.

For example:

```
filename = myclass.path + myclass.inputname
subprocess.call(["./code", filename])
```

This will run the code, and it passes the correct filename, but the C code will not read in any of the information from the file at all. If I pass something like:

```
./code "filename"
```

to the shell, where "filename" is actually what is printed when I use the print command in python, it works just fine.

Just for the sake of being complete, here are the lines that are relevant within my C code:

```
in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fscanf(in, "%s %d %d", variable1, &variable2, &variable3);
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: is "filename" printed with or without the quotes?  The shell will get rid of them, but subprocess won't.

Comment: Agreeing with @mgilson: what does `filename` look like? It might be a special character issue or something. (You also might want to use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of `myclass.path + myclass.inputname`).

Comment: Do `myclass.path` have a trailing slash? You might need to add a slash between the path and the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious, that you are not checking the result of `fopen` (are you using absolute path names?), your `fscanf` is wrong.  Try:

```
fscanf(in, "%s %d %d", variable1, &variable2, &variable3);
```

Another possibility is that the file is not in the format that `fscanf` expects - it is particularly picky about that and can easily crash your program if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` to your C code will let you see what it is receiving. Does the filename contain spaces? You might also like to check `argv[2]` in case it does.

Also, check the return value from `fopen()`. Is it `NULL`? (in which case it is failing to open the file).